# Requires 7-10 attempts to establish socket connection between Android and Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, android, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am trying to establish the socket connection between my Raspberry Pi and Android mobile.

The Raspberry Pi is running the server program and the Android phone is my client.

When I try to connect to server from my Android phone, the socket connection does not get established the first time. But if I close and run the app and repeat this procedure several (7+) times, the socket connection is established .

The socket connection is established 'first time' when trying from a laptop.

Any pointers?? Thank you

Programming language: Java.

## Server Code :

```
  ServerSocket serverSocket= new ServerSocket(6666);
  server = serverSocket.accept();
```

## Client code :

```
  Socket client = new Socket("192.168.0.108", 6666);
```

Comment: You need to post more code than that to get any help. For instance do you catch any exceptions in the client?

Comment: Following Exception caught "Connection timed out: connect"

Comment: If you connect wirelessly, probably you need check WIFI Lock...http://goltermann.cc/2011/11/android-accessing-wifi-even-in-standby-using-wakelock-wifilock-alarmmanager-and-services/